# Force a single application to use windows classic theme when running aero in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, themes, windows-themes

Is it possible to force a single application to use the windows classic them but the rest of windows 7 to use the aero theme?

The reason I ask is I am running proficy ifix 5.0 and when I run aero it adds annoying scrollbars to everything as the titlebar of the window is bigger than it normally is. Ifix 5.1 fixes this but I am forced to use 5.0 for certain clients.

I can just use classic theme in windows, but I was wondering if there is any way to force the different theme for a single application.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run the program in compatibility mode and select the option to disable desktop composition and/or visual themes. There are a number of different options and you may need to do a bit of experimentation to find the most effective.

Comment: This turns off the theme but the title bar is still the aero style size just not transparent. I would like it to run the title bar in classic theme and everything else in aero. I have even tried using windowblinds and ticking "do not skin this app" in the exceptions window. It does the same thing, it still uses the same thickness/size title bar just without the style/theme. I would like classic theme on one app, aero on everything else. I am starting to think this is not possible. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: No, you won't be able to draw the non-client are in classic style without using classic throughout.